# Problema con condición para validar en C

Tags: c

Tengo un problema con esta linea:

```c
while((respuesta != 'n' || respuesta != 'N'));
```

El programa sigue con el bucle y no reconoce los caracteres ingresados, pero si lo hago así:

```c
while(!(respuesta == 'n' || respuesta == 'N'));
```

Ahí si me lo toma, no sería igual una cosa que la otra? Disculpen si es una pregunta muy básica, recién comienzo en este mundo, gracias!

```c
//Ingresar un numero hasta que el usuario quiera e imprimir el minimo y el máximo.

int main(void)
{
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);

    int maximo;
    int minimo;
    int flag=1;
    int bufferInt;
    char respuesta;

    do
    {
        printf("\nIngrese un numero: ");
        scanf("%d",&bufferInt);


        if(flag==1)
        {
            maximo=bufferInt;
            minimo=bufferInt;
            flag=0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(maximo < bufferInt)
            {
                maximo=bufferInt;
            }
            if(minimo> bufferInt)
            {
                minimo=bufferInt;
            }
        }

        printf("Desea seguir ingresando datos? ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&respuesta);

    }  while((respuesta != 'n' || respuesta != 'N'));

    printf("El maximo es %d y el minimo es %d", maximo, minimo);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si usas el **o(OR)** nunca dejará de ser verdadero, por lo cual el bucle continua.

Ejm. Imagina que ingresas la letra **N mayúscula**, la expresión lógica a evaluar sería.

```
'N' != 'n' || 'N' != 'N';// la expresión queda así true || false => true
```

Si ingresas **n minuscula**

```
'n' != 'n'|| 'n' != 'N';// la expresión queda asi false || true => true
```

Y si ingresas otra letra diferente de **n** o **N** ejm **s**

```
's' != 'n' || 's' != 'N';// la expresión queda asi true || true => true
```

Por lo cual siempre te da como resultado **true**, lo cual ocasiona que el bucle no termine.

Si quieres que se acabe cuando se escriba la letra **n** o **N**, la lógica correcta es usar el operador lógico **y(AND)** de esta manera.

```
while ((respuesta != 'n' && respuesta != 'N'))
```

**Se interpreta así**. Mientras que lo que escriba el usuario sea diferente de **n** y ademas sea diferente de **N** entonces sígueme haciendo la pregunta.